# Unable to Access Phone Number from Google userinfo API Response in Golang (using golang.org/x/oauth2 and Google People API)

Tags: go, google-api, google-oauth

I've use this package
"golang.org/x/oauth2"
"golang.org/x/oauth2/google"

I try to get output of respond body by this code

```
var allUser map[string]interface{}
    client := getGoogleConfig().Client(context.Background(), &oauth2.Token{AccessToken: accessToken})
resp2, _ := client.Get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo")
    json.NewDecoder(resp2.Body).Decode(&allUser)
    fmt.Println(allUser)
```

but output like this

```
map[email:email email_verified:true given_name:name locale:th name:name picture:picturelink sub:somenumber]
```

this is my config code.
In this config profile aand public work correctly

```
*oauth2.Config {
    return &oauth2.Config{
        ClientID:     os.Getenv("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"),
        ClientSecret: os.Getenv("GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"),
        RedirectURL:  fmt.Sprintf("%s://%s:%s/api/auth/login/google-callback", os.Getenv("SERVER_PROTOCOL"), os.Getenv("SERVER_HOST"), os.Getenv("SERVER_PORT")),
        Scopes: []string{
            "profile",
            "email",
            "www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read",
            "www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read",
            "www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read",
        },
        Endpoint: google.Endpoint,
    }
```

I already try add "phonenumbers", "birthday" still don't get data what I want.

ChatGPT said it have to use another package but "golang.org/x/oauth2/google" don't work with that? then I try to read docs but still can't find something. Anyway will fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can find any information beside the basic profile data and email using the endpoint "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo".

For accessing the phone number and other personal details, you would need to use the [Google People API](https://developers.google.com/people), which allows for more granular access to the user's information.

Specifically, the [endpoint "https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=phoneNumbers"](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) will provide the user's phone number.

The official example is in the [People API Quick-start with Go](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/go#set_up_the_sample).
In your case, it would look like:

```golang
var person struct {
    PhoneNumbers []struct {
        Value string `json:"value"`
    } `json:"phoneNumbers"`
}

client := getGoogleConfig().Client(context.Background(), &oauth2.Token{AccessToken: accessToken})
resp, _ := client.Get("https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=phoneNumbers")
json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&person)

// Loop through the phone numbers if there are multiple
for _, phone := range person.PhoneNumbers {
    fmt.Println(phone.Value)
}
```

The new `person` struct is created to hold the "phoneNumbers" field from the response. Then a GET request to the Google People API will get the user's phone numbers.

Note that the returned phone numbers does not seem to be verified (meaning, the user can input any phone number in their profile). Only the user's primary email is verified by Google.